# Angular systemjs not working to load "system-importmap"

Tags: angular, webpack, systemjs

Here is my `angular.json` where i am added `systemjs` i am expecting to load the `systemjs-importmap` which added in `index.html` file. but not working.

`angular.json`:

```
 "scripts": [
              "node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.min.js",
              "node_modules/systemjs/dist/extras/amd.min.js",
              "node_modules/systemjs/dist/extras/named-exports.min.js",
              "node_modules/systemjs/dist/extras/named-register.min.js",
              "node_modules/import-map-overrides/dist/import-map-overrides.js"
            ],
```

here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>IIN</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="importmap-type" content="systemjs-importmap" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="preload" as="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <script type="systemjs-importmap">
      "imports":{
        "single-spa":"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/single-spa@5.8.2/lib/system/single-spa.min.js"
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

In case if I add the below link with `index.html` then it's calling.

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script> <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/systemjs/dist/extras/amd.js"></script>`

what is wrong here? why the `angular.json` script not executed? please help to understand the issue.

thanks in advance.